# How to generate an upload key for Google App Signing?

Tags: android, google-play, sign, signing, android-app-signing

I am currently struggling with the upload key, which is the new method of signing APK's to publish it to Google Play.

**What I have done**

1. I created a new app which should now on the play store.
2. I created an app entry on the Play console.
3. Then I activated `Google Play App Signing`
4. I uploaded my signed APK with a normal keystore file.

And then I get the following error message from the upload dialog.

> **Upload failed** You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is
>   also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are
>   enrolled in App Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key
>   before you upload it.

**What's the problem**

I did not find anything to upload an `upload key` or how to generate something like this. Is the upload key equal to the keystore file?

**What I've tried to do**

Then I looked at the documentation of app signing [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html). But I don't understand how I can create this upload key and send it Google.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly did you do on step 1?  Doesnt read well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [Help Page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423):

> **Upload key**: A new key you generate during your enrollment in the program. You will use the upload key to sign all future APKs prior to uploading them to the Play Console.

So it is just a new key you generate using the existing process.

Comment: But where can I generate this key. Normaly with the build in key store tool generator in Android Studio?

Comment: Yep. Exactly same process.

Comment: @ianhanniballake How about they key used for services used in the app like AdMobs, Analytics, etc. I'm assuming that should be the app signing key (managed by play console) and not the upload key.

Comment: @Vairavan - yes, those services rely on the app signing key. The Dev Console displays the MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256 of the signing key for just that reason.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thx. Is there a way to get the SHA for PEPK took downloaded from Play console?

Answer (score 64):

I just went through this exhausting process. I'm using React Native so I never even use Android Studio unless I need to launch a virtual device. I'm documenting this for myself and anyone else that has been traumatized by this experience. This is explicitly for the 'Upload Key' option. Google then swaps it out on Play so you aren't really responsible for making sure you don't lose the one and only key to your fortunes.

Open the 'android' file inside your React Native project in Android Studio. Build it and do whatever you have to so it gives you the options to produce an APK (unsigned or whatever). You can also just run it from here on a VD or a phone if it's attached. I had to do updates to get it to build so you may need to do the same.

First go to 'Build' in the menu:

[image]

This window will come up:

[image]

Click 'Create new...'

A dialog like this will come up. Fill it out with your info. Note that there are two separate passwords. Remember what you put there for later.

[image]

Go to someplace you want to store the key. In React Native, there is already a folder called 'keystores' at MyApp > android > app. Choose that as the key store path by clicking the '...' button.

[image]

Type in whatever you want your key called. I gave it the same name as the app.

This will bring you back to the previous dialog. Fill in the passwords from before and click 'Next'.

[image]

This will bring you to this dialog where you can choose where to put the apk. By default in React Native it goes to MyApp > android > app > app-release.apk. Click those two tick boxes otherwise you will have to change some configs or Google Play will reject it. They start out unchecked.

[image]

Go to this page in your Developer Panel. Click 'Edit Release'. This is presuming you've already set up a beta or alpha release. (Not covered here.)

[image]

That will bring you to this page. Drag and drop your apk here or upload with the button.

[image]

Please, Google, document this process somewhere! Peace out!

Comment: checking both boxes really makes the difference, I cowardly assumed that full apk signing was enough. thank you for the detail.

Comment: How do you get the upload key to match the upload certificate on the Play Store? I've enabled Google Play Signing but still have no clue how to get hold of my upload key. I only exported my app signing key from when I did not use Google Play Signing, then they provided me with an upload certificate but no key?!

Comment: @nickdnk If you go this route Google holds on to the key. That's sort of the point. You can't lose it this way. If you want to hold on to the key yourself you can generate the key yourself. It's a command line tool. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: @nickdnk I know it's kind of confusing but the key mentioned in these dialogs in this post is temporary. This doesn't give you the signing key. It gives you a key which you submit and Google swaps them out.

Comment: I know. I'm talking about the upload key. I only have the certificate, but I'm not sure where the key is coming from? I managed to upload an app today without problems though by importing the upload_key.der file into my keystore. I was just under the impression that the .der file only included the public part, but I guess not.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o59zF.png checking those 2 boxes is what I was missing. Great thing I stumbled here

Comment: Generate Signed APK doesn't exist as an option

Answer (score 16):

[image: Create a signed bundle in latest version of Android Studio, sign your app with jks as usual with "export encrypted key" checked.]

1. Create a signed bundle in latest version of Android Studio, sign your app with jks as usual except with "export encrypted key" checked.

[image: Your private key will be exported at ~/.android/private_key.pepk by default.]

2. Your private key will be exported at ~/.android/private_key.pepk by default.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the best answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, no google guide and nobody damn else mentions where the hell the private key is exported to.

Comment: is that the actual upload key though?

Comment: I dont have "export encrypted key" checkbox

Comment: @gmartinsnull yes it is.

Comment: how do you use the private_key.pepk to sign an update for your app?

Comment: @nt95 sign with your original key, .pepk is for opt in only. After you uploaded .pepk, you still sign your app with your original keystore.

Comment: @ShinChven I keep getting "Keystore Tampered with or password incorrect". The Keystore hasn't been modified since before the last release and the passwords are 100% correct. I've been stuck for 3 days, any advice?

Comment: I'm not seeing the 'Export encrypted key' option.  What version of AS are you using?

Comment: There is no such checkbox, what should we do?

Answer (score 13):

For me, the experience was different as of Feb 2019.
While uploading a signing key, I haven't completed the optional Upload Key section as it said that I can complete this step later.

[image]

After I have uploaded a signing key and pressed Finish, it said that now I have an upload key and I'm good to go even though I haven't created one.

[image]

It took me time to see that fingerprints of the signing certificate and upload certificate are identical, i.e. Google has silently registered my signing key as an upload key.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I'm getting the same. The first app signing page mentions that you can skip the upload key step for now and upload one later, I can't find an option anywhere to upload a new upload key.

Comment: my play console shows the same. Did you later figure out how to upload a 'upload key' later.

Also, in my case although i can upload app bundle, but Google doesn't calculate the binary diff when updating the app. Everytime a full apk is delivered. What about your's?

Comment: Hi @BorhnN - I was able to update the upload key later by contacting Google - I guess that's the only way. No troubles with app bundle from my side.

Comment: hi @yury.ku today I have tried to find place to upload Key. But It says need to contact developer support. Is there any other place to upload key ?

Comment: @SajithVijesekara As of Jan 2021, the only option is to contact Google support via this form: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key

Answer (score 5):

The Android Developer page you mentioned([Sign an APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk)) clearly lays out how to generate a key using Android Studio. Notice the [Generate a key and keystore](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) section.

An `upload key` is no different in terms of how it is created. It is only the purpose that makes it different from the signing key. Upload key is only used to upload the APK to the Google server so that they can authenticate you. Google then does the actual app signing for you.

Comment: I have tried following that page but the Build menu in my Studio 3.1.4 does not have the path stated so I cannot generate an upload certificate.  Also I am developing the app in Unity which will sign and export the APK so I have no project to open in Studio?

Comment: I also am using unity. what is the process to get android studio to open properly so I can access this signing menu?